# Does EF Code First have this Translate<T> method?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I haven't seen it anywhere, but I'm wondering if Code First has an implementation of the Translate method described [here](http://blog.cincura.net/231337-new-translate-and-executestorequery-executestorecommand-on-objectcontext-in-entity-framework-v4/). I'm currently using the Materialize method used in the EFExtensions project (modified for use with Code First), but I assume this method has these benefits:

- Probably knows what to do with complex types based on mappings instead of making assumptions off of property names.
- Probably returns the object proxies instead of the actual `T` specified.

Does anyone know enough about this method to comment on my assumptions, and does anyone know if this is available with Code First?

Comment: Ì'm not totally sure if it will work but have you already tried accessing your ObjectContext from your DbContext and then call the Translate function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just tried it. This example is in C#

```
using(YourDbContext ctx = new YourDbContext()) {
  ObjectContext x = ((IObjectContextAdapter)ctx).ObjectContext;

  var conn = ctx.Database.Connection;

  conn.Open();

  using (IDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
  {
    cmd.CommandText = "select * from YourType_Table";
    using (DbDataReader reader = (DbDataReader)cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
      YourType[] result = x.Translate<YourType>(reader).ToArray();
      Console.WriteLine(result.Length);
    }
  }
}
```

Regarding your questions:

- Only primitive types supported. For complex types it throws an `InvalidOperationException`.
- The objects returned are of proxy type.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for taking the time to test that out!